# how to use Python get the image URL and this URL is dynamically loaded after the page was loaded, and I can't find this URL in the API call?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My target is to get the Full image URL and download this picture.

Page URL:
https://allinone.pospal.cn/m#/details/6223421

The challenge is this URL is dynamically loaded after the page is loaded.

I can't find this information inside the any API calls. I want to know how this piece of information is being loaded into the page?

and What is the best way to get this full image URL? Is the selenium the only way to do?

The page source, there is no content inside yb-details-wrapper, so I can't get anything using the BeautifulSoup solely.

```
    <div id="detailsView" data-route="details" class='yb-page'>
        <div class="yb-page-inner">
            <div class="yb-header-home yb-header-tpl weui-flex">
                <img class="yb-logo" src="//imgw.pospal.cn/we/weidian/img/iconsV2/store.png" onerror="this.onerror = null; this.src = '//imgw.pospal.cn/we/weidian/img/iconsV2/store.png'" alt="" />
                <span class="yb-store-name">...</span>
                <span class="yb-filler"></span>
                <a href="#/search" class="yb-search-lnk"><img src="//imgw.pospal.cn/we/weidian/img/iconsV2/searchBlack@2x.png" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="yb-details-wrapper">
            </div>
        </div>
```

The target information was loaded dynamically somoe how...

```
<div class="yb-details-wrapper" style="">
   <div class="yb-details" p_uid="6223421">
      <div class="yb-details-inner">
         <div class="yb-details__hd">
            <div class="yb-details-photo">
               <img src="https://img.pospal.cn/productImages/4560246/1b7f3337-f67b-43c1-9b9c-b2817bdfd0e9_640x640.jpeg" onerror="_yb.errProdImg(this)" alt="">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="yb-details__bd">
            <div class="yb-details-sharebtn">
               <img src="//imgw.pospal.cn/we/mini/image/icons/share.png" class="yb-details-shareicon">Share
            </div>
            <div class="yb-details-title">新裝 馬爹利XO干邑(拱橋)700ml行貨</div>
            <div class="yb-details-price">MOP1360.00 <del>MOP1460.00</del></div>
            <div class="yb-details-numbers"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="yb-details-promote" id="YbPromote"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the url for the page? (to see what is loaded with requests / what information is available) The 200x200 image URL is the same as the 640x640 (just with the change in the size of the image requested in the string) if the product id is on the page you may be able to just scrape that and insert it into a generic link for the image that you want, but it is hard to help diagnose a problem with just images.

Comment: The URL of the page https://allinone.pospal.cn/m#/details/6223421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the url that you gave there seems to be an API endpoint with https://allinone.pospal.cn/wxapi/product/Attributes

to get the information that you require you could do something like:

```
import requests

data = {
    'id': '6223421', # this is the product id that you have in the original URL after /details/
    'includeSales': 'false',
    'incAttrPro': '',
}

response = requests.post('https://allinone.pospal.cn/wxapi/product/Attributes', data=data)
```

This should get you a response of

```json
{'successed': True, 'data': {'isPromotionProduct': True, 'name': '新裝 馬爹利XO干邑(拱橋)700ml行貨', 'defaultproductimage': {'id': '4505391', 'imagepath': 'https://img.pospal.cn/productImages/4560246/1b7f3337-f67b-43c1-9b9c-b2817bdfd0e9_200x200.jpeg'}, 'productimages': [{'id': '4505391', 'imagepath': 'https://img.pospal.cn/productImages/4560246/1b7f3337-f67b-43c1-9b9c-b2817bdfd0e9_200x200.jpeg'}], 'category': {'id': '207149', 'uid': '1636615051397614455', 'name': '馬爹利', 'type': 0}, 'sellPrice': 1360.0, 'sellPrice2': 1300.0, 'buyPrice': 0.0, 'discPrice': 1360.0, 'stock': 4.0, 'id': '6223421', 'uid': '109711149776695464', 'uidL': 109711149776695464, 'barcode': '3219820006186', 'productDisplayName': '新裝 馬爹利XO干邑(拱橋)700ml行貨', 'productOriginalPrice': 1460.0, 'description': '', 'isOutOfStock': False, 'attribute1': '', 'attribute2': '', 'attribute3': '', 'attribute4': '', 'attribute6': '700ml', 'attribute8': '', 'attribute9': '', 'attribute10': '', 'productOrder': 0, 'isEnableVirtualStock': False, 'productionDate': '', 'ignoreStock': False, 'productSeriesMaxPrice': 1360.0, 'productSeriesMinPrice': 0.0, 'extType': 1636615051397614455, 'dataIndex': 0, 'noStock': 0, 'PromotionStartDateTime': '2023-01-08 00:00:00', 'PromotionEndDateTime': '2023-03-31 23:59:59', 'NeedPromotionCoupon': False, 'OriginalSellPrice': 0.0, 'canAppointed': 0, 'createTime': '2021-11-11 15:18:46', 'productVideoPath': '', 'isServiceProduct': False, 'discounts': [{'discType': 2, 'discValue': 1360.0, 'enjoyCustomerDiscount': False, 'forCustomer': False, 'ruleUid': '1673153524851764253'}]}}
```

Which to access the information that you want you could do:

```
response.json()['data']['defaultproductimage']['imagepath'].replace('200x200', '640x640')
```

To get the image size you want of

https://img.pospal.cn/productImages/4560246/1b7f3337-f67b-43c1-9b9c-b2817bdfd0e9_640x640.jpeg